# How to add single space before multiple selected lines in dbt cloud editor?

Tags: editor, dbt

I have multiple lines selected in dbt cloud editor and want to add 2 spaces before all of them.
Ctrl + [ and Ctrl +] add and remove tabs only and do work to add or remove single spaces.